# What is the unique ID (identifier) for a Google GData ContactEntry object?

Tags: gdata-api, google-apps, google-contacts-api

Is there a unique identifier for the Google GData ContactEntry object? Basically, if there are two entries with names "Andy Lim" for example, we need to distinguish the entries and what is the identifier that can be used. Also, if we copy the contactentry to contacts folder in another google account, will the identifier stays the same, or will it change?

Regards,
Dicky

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [ContactEntry API documentation](http://code.google.com/apis/gdata/jsdoc/1.3/google/gdata/contacts/ContactEntry.html), the `ContactEntry` class extends `google.gdata.atom.Entry`, where it inherits a `getId()` method.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I assume that the id will change if we create a new contactentry then...